# Pandas печать чисел с разделителем тысяч пробел

Tags: python, pandas

Какую опцию нужно установить, чтобы при печати pandas `DataFrame` числа выводились в формате: 33 234 567.76 ? В функции `pd.set_option` не нашёл такого.

Answer (score 3):

```
import pandas as pd


def f(num: float) -> str:
    return f'{num:,.2f}'.replace(',', ' ')


pd.options.display.float_format = f
df = pd.DataFrame([123123.4567, 4545234.5678, 546566345.6789, 678655456.7890])
print(df)
```

Или, покороче, с лямбдой:

```
pd.options.display.float_format = lambda num: f'{num:,.2f}'.replace(',', ' ')
df = pd.DataFrame([123123.4567, 4545234.5678, 546566345.6789, 678655456.7890])
print(df)
```

```
               0
0     123 123.46
1   4 545 234.57
2 546 566 345.68
3 678 655 456.79
```